# Is possible to develop a simple socket app in Android main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

for simplicity purpose of demonstrating on how socket programming works in the Android platform, I want to develop a simple socket program without thread/asyntask and also (if possible) without exception caught.  Is that possible?  I've tried but it doesn't works (as pointed by many others that socket is better to be run at other thread).

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    tv.setText("Nothing from client yet");

 }


 public Void handleOnClick(View v) {
     Socket s = null;
     try {
     ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
     } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
     try {
     s = ss.accept();
     BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
     String st = null;
     st = input.readLine();
     mClientMsg = st;
     } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can develop anything without using AsyncTask, but I definitely don't recommend it as your application would block until the tasks completes (as I'm sure you already know)! In this case, your socket would need to response fast enough so that the OS doesn't kill your process (see discussions on [ANR here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/responsiveness.html)).

You will have to handle the Exceptions at one point or another. The best you can do is have your methods throw the exceptions and handle them wherever the method gets called, but this doesn't mean you won't have to handle them; this will just delay them.

```
public Void handleOnClick(View v) throws IOException {
    Socket s = null;
    ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
    s = ss.accept();
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    String st = null;
    st = input.readLine();
    mClientMsg = st;
}
```

If this is meant to be an example or demonstration for others, it should be well structured so that people learn to do things *correctly*. I would strongly encourage you to consider handling the exceptions where they should be handled (or throw more meaningful exceptions up the chain). Further, if you're teaching a class or an individual these things, you should demonstrate, at one point or another, how to avoid getting slapped with an ANR.